# Calculating Average Voltage

Tags: voltage

I am calculating an average voltage of a sine wave for the first half cycle ( which is 10 milliseconds) , and period is 20 milliseconds).

[image]

Comment: It really doesn't matter, because of the symmetry. You'll get the same answer both ways.

Comment: Well, if I change T from pi/2 to Pi the final answer won't change?

Comment: Right. The result of the integral will be twice as big, but since you divide that by T, the answer is the same. Note that \$\pi/2\$ is actually a *quarter* cycle; \$\pi\$ is a half cycle, and \$2\pi\$ gives you a full cycle. Of course, the average over a full cycle is zero.

Comment: what if T=20, and I am integrating from theta to 10-theta ? should I still use T=20 as period? also when I finding theta should it be in terms of angle or radians? given T=20 milliseconds? it makes more sense to use the radians, right?

Comment: Sorry, you lost me. You asked about calculating the average for a half cycle of a sine wave, and I pointed out that you get the same answer for a quarter cycle. The period of a sine wave is \$2\pi\$. What is theta?

Comment: I will add more detail to the question in a few mins. thanks

Comment: Half cycle is from 0 to Pi. Full cycle  is 0 to 2*Pi. You will get the same answer for the reason Dave mentioned. But if you want the half cycle, I suggest you use Pi rather than Pi/2, because it is not any more difficult, and it is what you are trying to calculate. Just make sure you use the correct time interval. In other words, if you use Pi, T should be 1/2f, but if you use Pi/2, then T should be 1/4f.

Comment: I just modified the question, please let me know what you think

Comment: @DaveTweed if I am getting his question the result is **not** the same. He wants the average of the "lower" wave but the question is: average on its period or on the "higher" wave period? And the answer as always is: it depends.

Comment: @DaveTweed I just realized he'd heavily modified the question, it was impossible to understand it before.

Comment: Yes that is correct, I'm calculating the average voltage of lower wave. I was also able to find the angle between two waves ( to find the lower and upper limits of the integral)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The integral for finding the average voltage isn't interested in the period of the sine wave.  It's only interested in the period over which you are measuring.  Since you are integrating over a half cycle, then use the period that identifies a half cycle in the integral.